# Bundle and minify using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, bundle, minify

i am using 
`System.Web.Optimization.JsMinify()` & `System.Web.Optimization.CssMinify()` in order to minify js files & css files and it's **working ok**.

After using those two functions > in chrome developer tools > sources > there is a new folder (with capital first letter) > in it there is a "bundle" folder and in it > the two min files.

Without the minification process there is no folder "bundle", i am wondering who is responsible of creating this folder and name it with capital first letter?

**Without** minification, the tree folder will look like that:

```
<name of the project with first lowercase letter>\*.js
```

**With** minification, (another folder is getting add, the tree folder will look like that:

```
<name of the project with first capital letter>\bundle\*.js
```

Comment: It's the Bundling module doing that. Is your question how to rename the virtual path? You do that in your BundleConfig.cs, assuming MVC 3-5.

Comment: i am using asp.net, not mvc.. how can i rename it?

Comment: Look where your bundles are configured. Look for something like `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle`.

Comment: Saying "I am using ASP.NET, not MVC" doesn't make sense. ASP.NET MVC is part of ASP.NET. Perhaps you meant to say "I am using Web Forms, not MVC"?

Comment: yes, and i found that place where the virtual path is sets "'new System.Web.Optimization.ScriptBundle('"

Comment: The virtual path set like this `ScriptBundle("~/bundle/js")` and it get insert bellow folder with capital first letter, if the minification is not happening all ths js/css file are getting inserted under other folder with the name of the project in lower case. who sets this folder?